# add character to the middle of a file name

Tags: bash, command-line

I need to add a character to the middle of a file name, I need to do this for about 8000 files all in the same directory.  I'm looking for a command-line option:

Example (all files that need renaming are five digits, they are in a directory that contains other six-digit filenames that do not need to be renamed):

```
01011
02022
12193
```

To:

```
010101
020202
121903
```

I've tried a couple of things: rename, mv, etc.  Similar to this ([Bash - Adding 0's in the middle of a file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242877/bash-adding-0s-in-the-middle-of-a-file-name)) but not exactly

Comment: Is this recursive, or are all of the files in the same directory?

Comment: Same directory.  Good question, I'll edit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can write:

```
for file in * ; do
    mv ./"$file" "${file:0:4}0${file:4}"
done
```

(See the explanation of `${parameter:offset}` and `${parameter:offset:length}` in [§3.5.3 "Shell Parameter Expansion" of the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).)

**Edited to add:** If you only want to capture a specific subset of files, you can change `*` to a more-specific pattern such as `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` (which matches filenames consisting of five digits).

Incidentally, you can format the whole thing on one line:

```
for file in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ; do mv "$file" "${file:0:4}0${file:4}" ; done
```

Comment: will this also affect six-digit files that do not need re-naming?

Comment: perfect. your edit turned the trick.  I really need to do more reading on bash.  thank you.

Comment: Edit section very well explained.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
for file in * ;  do mv "$file" "${file:0:4}0${file:4:1}" ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code.

```
rename -v -n "s/(S01S0[0-2][0-9])/\$1-/" *
```

`-n` to check the command output.

Comment: Can you tell the meaning of `S` in the regex. It doesn't run in my system.

Also could you tell why ``\ (backslash)`` is needed before $ symbol. I read some other rename answer which didn't use it and still worked, so when to use it?

Answer (score 0):

For a Windows prompt environment suposing that all the files start with the same name you could use rename.

```
rename 0101* 01010*
```

For a delimited size you could use

```
rename ????* ????0*
```

Real example

```
Pasta de C:\temp

10/08/2013  00:37    <DIR>          .
10/08/2013  00:37    <DIR>          ..
10/08/2013  00:37                 0 teste.txt
               1 arquivo(s)              0 bytes
               2 pasta(s)   846.577.762.304 bytes disponíveis

C:\temp>rename ???* ???0*

C:\temp>dir
O volume na unidade C nao tem nome.
O Número de Série do Volume é 7868-7679

Pasta de C:\temp

10/08/2013  00:38    <DIR>          .
10/08/2013  00:38    <DIR>          ..
10/08/2013  00:37                 0 tes0e.txt
               1 arquivo(s)              0 bytes
               2 pasta(s)   846.577.762.304 bytes disponíveis
```

Comment: nope, multiple names, however same number of characters.  Ex. 01011 or 02021 or 12159.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the assumptions you're making? Because I don't see how this could possibly work. Since Bash will expand the filename-patterns, the `rename` utility won't actually see them (it'll just get a long list of filenames); and also, I'm not aware of any `rename` utilities that perform this sort of matching across patterns.

Comment: Actually my solution was for the windows prompt command-line. That doesnt apply for bash environment

Comment: Even so, your solution does not work on my Windows box. Have you tested it?

Comment: My OS is Windows 7, dont know if your emulated Windows box "rename" would have the same implementation, probably not...